Why we don't use named local function to create "private function" in Lua？
Lua dosen't provide protection level keywords such as public / private / protected. If we want to create a field that only useable in current area, most of the time we use "local" keyword. for example:
-- field cannot be access in other Lua files
local privateVal = 0

-- field can be read or write outside
publicVal = 1

However, I hardly see the defination below:
-- define a named function as local, so that it cannot be use outside
local calc = function(item)
return item.a + item.b
end

-- use it locally
result = calc(myitem)

Why this style hardly use in Lua programming? I think maybe it is difficult to transmit the parameter "self", or there are some performance loss in function creation prograss.
Are there any other more critical reasons?

I have to disagree. It's very common to make functions local, unless they're part of a table. If someone makes a function global, they're polluting the global namespace.

The premise of this question is, in general, wrong. It would need to be specified more precisely in which context local variables are "hardly in use"; and even then it would probably still be quite an opinionated question.

Aside from the fact that your observation is simply wrong I want to point out that you are confusing the two concepts of scope and access.  private, public and protected are access modifiers. in order to mimic access modifiers in Lua you would have to use a combination limited scopes  and metatables. local is a scope modifier, it simply defines wether a value is local to the scope it was defined in. this can be far more restrictive than access modifiers.

there are many reasons for not using local functions. many people don't know better, people don't care, it does not matter in many scenarios or you simply need the functions in a global scope. one important reason for many people is that they want to work with functions defined in different files without having to provide and use an interface table for each file. using the global scope instead is convenient and again does not cause problems in most scenarios


Why this style hardly use in Lua programming?

On Github, searching for /local [\w_]+? = function/ language:Lua returns 181k files,  searching for "local function" language:Lua returns 631k files. I think this style should be quite common.
